# Chrome - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, iis

I am modifying a document management system for a company. Previously, this system is running on VM1 while it hosts document files on VM2. They are all on the same network.

Now, as i'm combining them into just 1 VM, I am having 'Not allowed to load local resource'. I read through a dozens of post regarding this but I can't seem to resolve it.

Here are some details:
VM running windows server with IIS.
Codes are in php and js.

Current VM setup: 192.168.0.79
Fileserver is located on: 192.168.0.79/FileServer

As you can see, they are all on the same domain so it shouldn't face this issue.
Below is an example of the link:
file://192.168.0.79/FileServer/document/HOLDINGS%20PTE%20LTD/1-SecDirRes.doc

This links work when enterred in the chrome url bar, but when using through the site, it gives the error.
Anyone have any ideas? I've also tried more additional slashes, same result.

Comment: try to change file:// to http://

Comment: Thanks VikingCode, unfortunately i can't do that because the requirements for this is to have it open 'microsoft word' directly. It used to work before i merged the VMs and this was how they did it.

Comment: do you connect to the server with https?

Comment: nope, as they are all on the same network, https isn't used.